# Can I seperate android material tabs from the apps tool bar?

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewgroup

simple yes or no I think will be suffice,I know I can create my own tabs and make them look like the new material designed ones and have complete control over there position, but I'm kinda hoping I can achieve my desired result using the support library,
I've followed a tutorial to set up my material tabs, they need some asphetic polish but they work great.

[image: screenshot 1]

Except id actually like them to be half way down my apps view like this-

[image: screenshot 2]

I've tried nesting the views but have so far only managed to move the entire screen.

[image: screenshot3]

does anyone have a quick fix or workaround for this or is this just how it is?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout    
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabGravity="fill" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/plus" />

  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please share your XML/layout code on this so I can review it

Comment: certainly, @Magnar ive added the code to the question

Answer (score 0):

manage to work around this it was because my tabs were nested in my toolbar, so taking it out enabled me to move them around to where i wanted

Comment: You should place the code fix so others can benefit from it